# SpringBoot on Google AppEngine Could not find or load main class

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, deployment

I create an application using spring boot and I try to deploy it to Google AppEngine, but when I my application, I saw into logs this message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class [MyMainClass]
```

this is the `app.yaml` file

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F1
env: standard
entrypoint: java -cp "*" [MyMainClass] [ProjectName]-0.4.0.war

handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|env))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

this is the `appengine-web.xml` file

````xml
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java11</runtime>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="classes/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
    <public-root>/src/main/webapp</public-root>
    <resource-files>
        <include path="/**.xml" />
        <exclude path="**/Icon\n" />
        <exclude path="**/Icon\n\r" />
        <exclude path="**/Icon\r" />
        <exclude path="**/Icon\r\n" />
    </resource-files>
</appengine-web-app>```
````

Comment: Please read this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-google-app-engine

Comment: Could you try to update your Cloud SDK and App Engine Java components by running `gcloud components install app-engine-java` and `gcloud components update`, and then try to deploy the application again?

Comment: @DenisT. yes my Cloud SDK is up to date

Comment: Simon Martinelli that article is for java8 and for flex environment, my project is for java11 and standard environment

Answer (score 1):

I fix in this way:

- into `POM` I set package to `jar`

```xml
...
<groupId>MyPackages</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<version>MyVersion</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
```

- into `app.yaml` I set the entry point

```
entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar target/[MyPackage.MyProject-MyVersion].jar
```

Comment: Glad to hear that the issue was solved. I am adding this [**link**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#application_startup) to the GCP documentation on **Java 11 application startup** for the further reference.